# Does the Portuguese word "você" comes from "vosotros"?

Tags: etimologia, origem-histórica

I always wanted to know the reason why "vosotros" is not used in Hispanic America, but its biggest cousin Brazil has a very similar word "você"; so I suspect its a remaining form of "vosotros" that migrated to Portuguese language from Spanish.

In American Spanish they don't use "vosotros" but Brazilian Portuguese still uses "você"; does this word come from the old Spanish "vosotros"?

Comment: Buena pregunta, me sorprende que aún no se haya respondido acá antes. Una observación, el español *es* latino por definición. Aún no conozco algo como un ‘español no-latino’

Comment: En cuanto a por qué ‘vosotros’ no se usa más en L.A., [acá hay una discusión al respecto](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/13516/por-qu%C3%A9-los-espa%C3%B1oles-usan-la-palabra-vosotros-pero-los-latinoamericanos-no) , aunque es una mera especulación

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not about Spanish.

Comment: @Lambie The answer given (and accepted) is in Spanish, could you contact its author, tac, over Spanish SE about whether he'd be up to provide a version in English? As it stands we would have to delete it.

Comment: @stafusa A moderator should be able to transfer it. I don't know how to do that but the mods here should know. Don't you?

Comment: @Lambie I'll have to ask around — I don't know if they'll be notified if I write them here, and I can't write to them there since I haven't joined, that's why I asked you.

Comment: Banquen banquen, ahora me encargo...

Comment: Ya edité la respuesta, por favor corrijan los errores ortográficos y gramaticales. Y si sienten muy necesario reformular algo porque suena muy raro, háganlo sin problema. Y más les vale ahora, que la respuesta está traducida, que revienten los +1. Los dejo gente, éxitos...

Comment: @tac Muchas gracias!

Comment: We say South American or Latin American Spanish, fyi.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Resposta breve: **não**.

Historicamente (etimologicamente), **você** vem de **vossa mercê**, que significa **vuestra merced**. Ao mesmo tempo, a última deu origem a **usted**.

Equivalência etimológica:

> **vossa mercê** --> **você**
> **vuestra merced** --> **usted**

Atualmente, esse pronome perdeu seu tom formal em Brasil (em geral). Nessa situação é traduzido como **vos** o **tú**. Enquanto que em Portugal e áreas minoritárias do Brasil, o pronome preserva seu tom formal, nessa situação é traduzido como **usted**.

Equivalência atuais:

> **você** (informal; Brasil) = **vos** (voseo) o **tú** (tuteo)
> **você** (formal; Portugal e áreas minoritárias do Brasil) = **usted**

Não há relacionamento entre *você* e *vosotros* em nenhum caso. Bem, na realidade se formos mais detalhistas, a conexão seria com *vossa/vuestra* que é o possessivo associado a *vosotros*. Mas, pelo que sei, em nenhum momento na história ‘você’ e ‘vosotros’ eram equivalentes. Em todo caso, deveria dizer que atualmente ‘vosotros’ é equivalente a ‘você**s**’.

Por que alguns pronomes são usados na América Latina e outros na Europa? Ninguém tem certeza, há várias conjecturas. A minha é muito simples: como os países do Novo Mundo buscaram sua própria identidade, isso também se aplica ao idioma; ou seja, nós, latino-americanos, buscamos ‘deliberadamente’ (mas inconscientemente) nossas próprias marcas registradas no discurso a fim de distinguirmos dos europeus—e vice-versa!

[Mais informações sobre a origem do você](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voc%C3%AA)

Comment: Tú teoría final no me parece plausible y menos en este caso. Simplemente el español evolucionó de forma distinta. En España se dejó de usar y en Argentina se mantuvo. Y no tengo yo esa sensación de que busquemos en la antigua metropoli explicitamente palabras nuevas para diferencianos. Por otro lado echo en falta alguna referencia que apoye tu respuesta.

Comment: Yo reemplazaría ‘explícitamente’ por ‘inconscientemente’. Tampoco digo que las palabras se adoptan de un día para el otro. Por otro lado, si tanto te interesa ver una referencia, ahí la dejé

Comment: Muito obrigado por se dispor a traduzir para nós, tac!